# ADO.NET SqlData Client connections never go away

Tags: ado.net, connection-pooling, sqlconnection

An asp.net application I am working on may have a couple hundred users trying to connect. We get an error that the maximum number of connections in the pool has been reached. I understand the concept of connection pools in ADO.NET although in testing I've found that a connection is left "sleeping" on the ms sql 2005 server days after the connection was made and the browser was then closed. I have tried to limit the connection lifetime in the connection string but this has no effect. Should I push the max number of connections? Have I completely misdiagnosed the real problem?

Comment: Are the connections actually getting *Closed*?

Comment: I checked the code again and we do Close the connection in the code but on the SQL server (running sp_who2) I can see the connection remains. After investigating further I found an msdn blog which confirms there is a bug when using "Connection Lifetime=(seconds)". This value has no effect. http://blogs.msdn.com/selvar/archive/2008/05/01/connectionlifetime-attribute-in-the-sqlconnection-connection-string-is-not-honored.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your database connections must either be wrapped in a try...finally:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
myConnection.Open();
try
{
}
finally
{
   myConnection.Close();
}
```

Or...much better yet, create a DAL (Data Access Layer) that has the Close() call in its Dispose method and wrap all of your DB calls with a *using*:

```
using (MyQueryClass myQueryClass = new MyQueryClass())
{
   // DB Stuff here...
}
```

A few notes: ASP.NET does rely on you to release your Connections.  It *will* release them through GC after they've gone out of scope but you can *not* count on this behavior as it may take a very long time for this to kick in - much longer than you may be able to afford before your connection pool runs out.  Speaking of which - ASP.NET actually pools your connections to the database as you request them (recycling old connections rather than releasing them completely and then requesting them anew from the database). This doesn't really matter as far as you are concerned: you still must call Close()!

Also, you can control the pooling by using your connection string (e.g. Min/Max pool size, etc.).  See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(VS.80).aspx) on MSDN for more information.

Comment: I've inherited the current code and we're moving to an orm soon so I hope this may fix the problem. I'll take a look at closing the connection in a finally block

Comment: I've checked the code again and we do close the connection properly as you mentioned. I've isolated the code in a unit test but the connection on the SQL server hangs out for more than 24 hours.

Comment: CountCet: I'm not surprised that SQL server still shows the connection as open since the pool keeps it open.  The issue is why your pool is filling up - why the pool's connections to your app aren't being released.  If the "Close()" method is called and you go check the database, you will NOT see the connection disappear (that is, running sp_who db isn't the appropriate diagnostic).

Now, in my code there are dozens and dozens of points at which the database comes into play.  You say that you've "isolated the code" - do you only have one point through which you connect with the database?